# How to build Docker image automatically using Spring Boot Maven Plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I want to build the Docker image of my Spring Boot application on GitLab automatically using [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/).

I followed [6. Packaging OCI Images](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.3.RELEASE/maven-plugin/reference/html/#build-image) but I get an arror:

> Unable to read jar file /builds/test/test-parent/test-application/target/test-application-1.1.14-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar.original

**Configuration**

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <executable>true</executable>
        <classifier>exec</classifier>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>build-info</goal>
                <goal>build-image</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

**Logs**

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE:build-image (default) on project test-application: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE:build-image failed: Unable to read jar file /builds/test/test-parent/test-application/target/test-application-1.1.14-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar.original -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE:build-image (default) on project test-application: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE:build-image failed: Unable to read jar file /builds/test/test-parent/test-application/target/test-application-1.1.14-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar.original
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.3.RELEASE:build-image failed: Unable to read jar file /builds/test/test-parent/test-application/target/test-application-1.1.14-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar.original
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to read jar file /builds/test/test-parent/test-application/target/test-application-1.1.14-SNAPSHOT-exec.jar.original
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state (Assert.java:97)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.ImagePackager.packageImage (ImagePackager.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.ImagePackager.packageImage (ImagePackager.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo$PackagedTarArchive.writeTo (BuildImageMojo.java:280)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport$WritableHttpEntity.writeTo (HttpClientTransport.java:196)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RequestEntityProxy.writeTo (RequestEntityProxy.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.sendRequestEntity (DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:156)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doSendRequest (HttpRequestExecutor.java:238)
    at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute (HttpRequestExecutor.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute (MainClientExec.java:272)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute (ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute (RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute (RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute (InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute (CloseableHttpClient.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute (HttpClientTransport.java:128)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.execute (HttpClientTransport.java:123)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.transport.HttpClientTransport.put (HttpClientTransport.java:106)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.DockerApi$ContainerApi.uploadContainerContent (DockerApi.java:242)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.docker.DockerApi$ContainerApi.create (DockerApi.java:227)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Lifecycle.createContainer (Lifecycle.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Lifecycle.run (Lifecycle.java:146)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Lifecycle.execute (Lifecycle.java:113)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.executeLifecycle (Builder.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.buildpack.platform.build.Builder.build (Builder.java:71)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.buildImage (BuildImageMojo.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.BuildImageMojo.execute (BuildImageMojo.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
```

How to build Docker image of my Spring Boot application on GitLab automatically using Spring Boot Maven Plugin?